# how to access an external stylesheet through the Document interface in Java?

Tags: java, css, dom, document, javafx-2

I have an interface reference (**instanceof** Document) pointing to a valid object. The problem is that I want to view the **style** attribute associated with a particular element in *DOM*, but it will only expose **inline** attributes (while *style* has been set through an **external** stylesheet). The end goal is to acquire a reference to **ViewCSS**, as I want to view the associated computed style - how would I do this? I'm presuming, that acquiring a **DocumentView** object might be needed (if so, how, as I did not find any method that will return the aforementioned object)?

---

```
Document document = ...;

document.getImplementation().hasFeature("Views", "2.0"));
```

this returns **true**.

```
Object obj = document.getImplementation().getFeature("Views", "2.0");
```

this throws an **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.**

---

What am I doing wrong, how to fix it and what is the best way to go about this (I want to view/**change** the associated computed style for this document)? Thank you.

**Edit**:

I think this is an important part of details that should have been provided initially:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at com.sun.webpane.webkit.dom.NodeImpl.getFeature(Unknown Source)
```

the **Document** object returned was from a **javafx** package triggered on **WebEngine**.

Comment: I believe you met a bug. I've filed it as http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this fragment solves your problem:

```
Document doc = ???;
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)doc;
final HTMLBodyElement body = (HTMLBodyElement)htmlDoc.getBody();

//JS [window] access
DOMWindowImpl wnd =
        (DOMWindowImpl)((DocumentView)htmlDoc).getDefaultView();

//Style access
CSSStyleDeclaration style = wnd.getComputedStyle(body, "");
assertEquals("Style extraction", "blue", style.getPropertyValue("background-color"));
```

Comment: hmm, sorry, what am I missing - is `DOMWindowImpl` a part of JFX2.2? otherwise what is the proper package path for it in 2.1? Same goes for `assertEquals`.

Comment: [DOMWindowImpl] is a part of JFX2.2 (very last moment), but it is undocumented and subject for changes.
That part of project was essentially changed and is not accessible in JFX2.1. The [assertEquals] is a unit test validation procedure (CSS "background-color" has a "blue" value).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [Source/WebCore/dom/Node.idl] in Webkit does not support [getFeature] method:

```
#if 0
        DOMObject          getFeature(in DOMString feature, 
                                      in DOMString version);
        DOMUserData        setUserData(in DOMString key, 
                                       in DOMUserData data, 
                                       in UserDataHandler handler);
        DOMUserData        getUserData(in DOMString key);
#endif /* 0 */
```

So, the only thing I could do - make a stub for it in
[com.sun.webpane.webkit.dom.DOMImplementationImpl.java], 
[com.sun.webpane.webkit.dom.NodeImpl.java]

```
public Object getFeature(String feature, String version) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

That is a [feature](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23857).
Regards,
-uta

Answer (score 1):

Can you check what class is being returned by document.getImplementation() (try to print its .getClass())

My best guess is .getFeature() is an enhancement in Java 5 and it looks like there is a half baked implementation of DOMImplementation in your class path. Get the real class being loaded and check its doc so see if they have an implementation for getFeatures() method or not.

Comment: I've deleted my previous wall of comments, heh. `com.sun.webpane.webkit.dom.DOMImplementationImpl` for **getImplementation()** and `com.sun.webpane.webkit.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl` for `javafx.​scene.​web.​WebEngine` / **getDocument()**. It seems this might be indeed the case of a half-baked implementation..